# JavaScript Messed up OnChange File Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do not understand why web technology is so messed up.
I am trying to accomplish something really easy. But found out that it has bugs.

So what I am trying to do is load in a div the image selected by user. It works first time. But once I select browse and select another image it doesn't work. What is wrong here?

```
<input type="file" id="imgUploadButton" class="default" name="picture" onchange="imageUploaded(event);" />
```

And this is the Javascript code

```
var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var imgtag = document.getElementById("imageTool");

imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;
reader.onload = function(event) {
    imgtag.src = event.target.result;
 };
 reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would define the onchange event a bit differently if I were you, for example by doing the following:

```
<input type="file" id="imgUploadButton" />
<div><img id="imageTool" /></div>
<script>
  // Create a self-executing anonymous function so that the window
  // isn't being cluttered with global variables
  (function() {
    // First get the file element
    var fileElement = document.getElementById('imgUploadButton');

    // Now if we found the file element, add the onchange event, 
    // doing it like this maximizes compatibility
    if (fileElement) fileElement.onchange = imageUploaded;

    // Define your imageUploaded function, as it will get hoisted
    // anyway
    function imageUploaded(event) {
      var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var imgtag = document.getElementById("imageTool");
      imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        imgtag.src = event.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
    }
  }());
</script>
```

Best is to do this on the end of the `body` tag, of course. See my [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kabw2fdf/1/).

Comment: Thanks. 
I have tried this earlier too. It works. Please see the updated question with edits. I will appreciate your help. I have wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and not the answer please :)

Comment: Sincere apologies. Mad a mistake. The button's unresponsive here. Posted a new question. Please see here and answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696003/jquery-imagecrop-with-html

Comment: Some fiddling. 
Marking your answer. I used AJAX to solve the problem though.

Comment: Thanks, hope it wasn't too frustrating :)