# Javascript inline script onchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having a problem on making my code to adjust to my web server, because of the security purposes, all inline javascript code to my html is not allowed.

everything is already okay i'm just having a hard time converting my other code to pure javascript

Here is my existing code,,,

```
<label class=qrcode-text-btn><input type=file accept="image/*" capture=environment id="openQRCamera" tabindex=-1></label>
```

the original code is this

```
<label class=qrcode-text-btn><input type=file accept="image/*" capture=environment onchange="openQRCamera(this);" tabindex=-1></label>
```

the `onchange` is not working because it is inline in the html.

this function needs to open a camera and detect if there is a qr that exists.

here is what i have now on converting it.

```
document.querySelector("#openQRCamera").addEventListener('onchange', (node) => {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        node.value = "";
        qrcode.callback = function(res) {
         if(res instanceof Error) {
           alert("There is no QR detected");
         } else {
           node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
         }
        };
        qrcode.decode(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
});
```

here is the original code

```
  function openQRCamera(node) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      node.value = "";
     qrcode.callback = function(res) {
        if(res instanceof Error) {
          alert("There is no QR detected");
        } else {
          node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
        }
      };
      qrcode.decode(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
  }
```

i am using this website as my source of code, everything is working fine in my localhost, but the server is just strict, and i think that's normal for all the websites.

`https://www.sitepoint.com/create-qr-code-reader-mobile-website/`

i just been stuck and try to do other solution like adding event listener, and append of input just by using jquery, but it's not working. thanks in advance.

Comment: SO you want to do it without an inline function in HTML ? did you try `document.querySelector("#openQRCamera").onchange = function() { } ` ?

Comment: `addEventListener('change' ...` change `onchange` to `change` on your `addEventListener`

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691132/javascript-messed-up-onchange-file-input

Comment: @MihaiT yes i tried, i tried putting alert on each line, but it seems that, it doesn't go inside the ```reader.onload = function() {}```

Comment: @SameeraLiyanage it still did not work for me :(

Comment: so then it's not a problem with the `onchange` function ( which gets fired ) but the `reader.onload` function ?

Comment: yes, i think i'm having the problem to the arrow function,

Comment: @Janessa  https://codepen.io/sameeraliyanage/pen/jONJLNx this is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener you are using is faulty, instead of listenning to 'onchange' you have to listen to 'change' like so:

document.querySelector("#openQRCamera").addEventListener('change', () => {

//remove the node as parameter and get it with javascript:

var node = document.getElementById('openQRCamera');
..